# How to highlight a type in comment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments

I saw the following comment and noticed that Visual Studio highlights the type (DateTime).

[image]

How would I do this in my own C# comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `<see cref="member"/>`

I think this is [answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`<see cref="">`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) tag for that:

```
<see cref="DateTime">
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think this is what you need: Location: `Tools/Options/Envoirment/Fonts and Colors`